# Realm: Cannot invoke 'add(_:update:)' with an argument list of type '(String)'

Tags: swift, database, realm, swift4, local-database

I have the following code

```
import RealmSwift
class myclass: NSObject {
  let realm = try! realm()
  @objc dynamic var id = String()

  func writeRealmLocal() {
    try! realm.write {
       realm.add(id)
    }
  }
}
```

But, i throw the following error: **Cannot invoke 'add(_:update:)' with an argument list of type '(String)'**

I am following the realm documentation but I cannot solve this error, any ideas?

[image: Error Realm and Swift 4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Realm incorrectly. Realm saves object instances, each of which are of type `Object`. [Here](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/) is reference for the class.

If you wish to save you `MyClass`, you could do the following,

```
import RealmSwift

class MyClass: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id = String()
}
```

And, use `Realm` object to store the object.

```
let realm = try! Realm()
realm.write {
 realm.add(MyClass())
}
```

I suggest you to go through the [Getting Started](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/) section in realm.io page. And if you wish to see documentation for classes, go [here](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Object.html)

Comment: I just made that change, but now I throw the following error: Cannot convert value of type '(MyClas).Type' to expected argument type 'Object'

Comment: Convert NSObject to Object. See my post, I use Object